# CS0118: 'ServerSidePost.WebForm1.btnLogin' is a 'field' but is used like a 'method'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For line 18 which is the asp:Button line I am getting the error  CS0118 saying that it is being used as a method instead of a field.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1"  method="post"  runat="server">
   <div>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Width="294px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
   </div>
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" PostBackUrl="~/WebForm2.aspx" runat="server"       Height="101px" OnClick="btnLogin"></asp:Button>
        </p>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the ID of your button has the same name as its OnClick handler. Either rename your method to something like btnLoginOnClick or put another ID.

Comment: I renamed the method like you said, however I ended with a different error this time - CS1061: 'ASP.webform1_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btnLogin' and no extension method 'btnLogin' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.webform1_aspx' could be found - (My teacher has thrust me into doing this and thus have no prior experience in c#, so if am making a blind stupid error....sorry)

Comment: To fix this easily, just go into designer mode and double click on the button. It should automatically make you a click handler and won't need to worry about naming it.

Comment: I tried that and the original error message came up when I debugged it.

Comment: Well just go to the `Name` property and call it `btnLogin` and go to the `OnClick` and call it `btnLogin_Click`. Then go to your C# code behind and make sure its called `btnLogin_Click` there too.